# how to truncate html string in js

Tags: javascript

I have a page displaying text in html entity into a `div` node, like below one:

`&#x3C;p&#x3E;isdjf&#x3C;&#47;p&#x3E;osdf&#x26;kdjf;&#x27;ldsf.&#x22;jdof&#x26;ids`

want to truncate it to 10 letters length in js, but want to avoid break html entities, how to achieve that correctly? `substr`?

**html entity break** is as below:

```
var str = '0123456&#x3E;abc';
console.log( str.substr(0,10) );  // -> "0123456&#x"
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by *avoid break html entities* ?

Comment: what is html entities break?

Comment: @sumeetkumar, please see update

Answer (score 2):

```
function truncate(enitityEncodedString){

    var string, count, pos;

    string = '';

    count = 0;

    while(count <= 10){

        if(enitityEncodedString.search(/&#.{2,3};/) === 0){

            pos = enitityEncodedString.indexOf(';') + 1;

            string += enitityEncodedString.substr(0, pos);

            enitityEncodedString = enitityEncodedString.substr(pos);

        }else{

            string += enitityEncodedString[0];

            enitityEncodedString = enitityEncodedString.substr(1);

        }

        count++;

    }

    return string;


}
```

Check for html entities at the beginning of the encoded string. If so, concat that html entity to the return string (I used .indexOf() to get the length of the html entity, assuming the first semicolon means the end of that same html entity). Otherwise, just add the first character to the return string. Repeat untill you got 10 characters.

Maybe not the prettiest way, but it works.